# Travis build exited with 1 but local check is fine - R package

Tags: r, travis-ci

I have an R package that was passing all Travis CI builds successfully and randomly started to fail. I've pondered where the problem is at but I can't seem to fix it.

[Here](https://github.com/cimentadaj/ess/blob/dev_branch/.travis.yml) is the travi.yaml from the package

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/cimentadaj/ess/builds/317031912) is the failing log of Travis-CI

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/cimentadaj/ess/builds/316873639#L1495) is the last log the passed (about 2-3 logs behind the last fail)

I think the fail might be related to line 1495 from the last log that passed:

```
The command "for name in $(find "${RCHECK_DIR}" -type f -name "*out");do echo ">>> Filename: ${name} <<<";cat ${name};done" exited with 0.
```

which **does not** appear in the failed log from above. After thoroughly checking my tests with devtools:

```
R CMD check results
0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

I don't know what it might be. I thought it was related to some examples taking too much time (some examples pass the 5 second thresholds, so I comment them out but the failing persists. I tried posting this in the [Rstudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/travis-build-exited-with-1-but-local-check-with-devtools-is-fine/3645) but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: What environment do you have locally? Also can you share the diff between the last success and the first fail? i'd try stepping through whatever you did pushing to Travis with each change. Often a difference may be due to a local file that hasn't been committed or a local environment setting.